# HttpRequestBase.GetBufferedInputStream not found when doing a WebAPI 2 JSON Post

Tags: json, visual-studio, mono, asp.net-web-api2, xamarin.mac

1. Created a MVC5 WebAPI2 project using Visual Studio
2. Created a basic JSON POST
3. Post arguments cause HttpRequestBase.GetBufferedInputStream not found  failure

Works on:

1. Windows with visual studio

Fails on:

1. OSX Xamarin
2. Gentoo Xamarin

Test application: [Mono MVC5 Web API2 Test Case](https://github.com/shaunstepanowich/mono-webapi2-test)

Test procedure:

1. run the MVC application in xamarin
2. On load the page will do a ajax post to the server.
3. a) server will return a 500 error on failure

   b) console.log post arg on success

   ```
   Error: {
       "Message": "An error has occurred.",
       "ExceptionMessage": "Method 'HttpRequestBase.GetBufferedInputStream' not found.",
       "ExceptionType": "System.MissingMethodException",
       "StackTrace": " at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent.get_StreamContent () [0x00008] in :0

                       at System.Web.Http.WebHost.HttpControllerHandler+LazyStreamContent.CreateContentReadStreamAsync () [0x00000] in :0

                       at System.Net.Http.HttpContent+c__async2.MoveNext () [0x00095] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/System.Net.Http/System.Net.Http/HttpContent.cs:159

                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.IO.Stream].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372

                       at System.Net.Http.HttpContentExtensions+d__0`1[System.Object].MoveNext () [0x00080] in :0

                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Object].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372

                       at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.FormatterParameterBinding+d__0.MoveNext () [0x000a5] in :0

                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:124

                       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding+d__0.MoveNext () [0x000a0] in :0

                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:124

                       at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult+d__2.MoveNext () [0x0008f] in :0

                       --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

                       at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.ExceptionServices/ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:61

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:201

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:170

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:142

                       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage].GetResult () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.0.0-branch-c5sr4/bockbuild-mono-4.0.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.0.4/external/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:372

                       at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher+d__1.MoveNext () [0x0018d] in :0 "
   }
   ```

Comment: I've experienced the same problem: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=34011

Comment: Yeah, I found that, but I'm not sure it's a bug or not, or is there some way to avoid it.

Comment: Async operations are not fully implemented in mono mcs, as written on their blog - http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility/
The workaround i di for my project is to use HttpContect.Current.Request.InputStream to get posted data and create an extension class inspired by https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs to serialize.
Then compilation directive for mono/windows

Answer (score 9):

I too had this issue after promising a client I could write an ASP.NET 5 WepAPI application and deploy it in their Ubuntu 14.04 server. *Yay.*

**Basically, you need to upgrade to a bleeding edge version to get this feature supported correctly**. On Ubuntu, you can use the official nightlies repository. Note however that, on Ubuntu, you may need to list all installed packages using `dpkg` and do a grep for `mono` and make sure that you fully purge previous installations (manual and package-manager installed alike). You'll have this issue especially if you've installed from source.

Again, in the context of Ubuntu, you can use `whereis mono` to track down everywhere that it might be. This must be done because otherwise you're going to have conflicts, as you'll have multiple versions of mono competing in your ENV.

For OSX and other platforms, you can find official information and links to nightlies [here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/weekly-packages/).

Again, for Ubuntu, here's how to add the binary nightlies to your sources:

```
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian nightly main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-nightly.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: For me it worked with `sudo apt-get install mono-complete` rather than just an update.

Comment: @shturm Yeah by now they might have pushed the changes to the official repo.

Answer (score 2):

This API was added just [recently](https://github.com/mono/mono/commit/303d876370017774445c71736cf34e851e5cb037) into Mono (first version to have it is 4.3.2.467). Then please upgrade your Mono version to be able to use this feature.

(Or use ASP.NET Core, which renders WebAPI infrastructure obsolete, and also runs in Linux out of the box without the need of Mono, AFAIU.)

NB: Yes, 4.3.x is too bleeding edge at the time of this writing, then you might need to upgrade Mono yourself outside the boundaries of your distribution or accessing unstable channels. Or build Mono yourself, but **under no circumstance** follow blindly unofficial guides about how to compile Mono yourself, or install some random packages (unless you know what you're doing). You should always refer to packages signed-off by the official sources, such as the [nightlies](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/getting-started/install/weekly-packages/) ones, or use [official guides on how to install versions of mono in parallel](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/compiling-mono/parallel-mono-environments/) (otherwise you may run into troubles about conflicting distro packages, or wrong prefix being used for installation that doesn't work out of the box, etc).

Answer (score 1):

Context to reproduce is described in the first post.

The main problem is that "HttpRequestBase.GetBufferedInputStream" is not available in Mono version (4.2).

Async operations are not fully implemented in mono mcs, as written on [their blog](http://mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility).
The workaround I did for my project is to use HttpContect.Current.Request.InputStream to get posted data and create an extension class inspired by [aspnetwebstack repository](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/4e40cdef9c8a8226685f95ef03b746bc8322aa92/src/System.Net.Http.Formatting/HttpContentExtensions.cs) to serialize.

Then compilation directive for mono/windows

Source and example is available [here](https://gist.github.com/madagaga/6c13fdb14a3c71f883a3618be2e19a31).

It work on my server mono v4.2.x (Debian 8), tested on Windows and Osx.

Comment: Link only answers AND code without any explanation are not acceptable here. Can you please include all relevant data in your answer? Link rot etc.

Comment: The main problem is that "HttpRequestBase.GetBufferedInputStream" is not available in Mono version (4.2)

 
Async operations are not fully implemented in mono mcs, as written on their blog - mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/compatibility The workaround i di for my project is to use HttpContect.Current.Request.InputStream to get posted data and create an extension class inspired by github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/… to serialize. Then compilation directive for mono/windows

Comment: That sounds like a good, alternative solution and I'd like to upvote your answer for it. Can you edit the answer itself to fully explain this, and include relevant source in **inside the answer**? Comments will be deleted over time, and links will rot. Put all data that you want to survive **inside the answer**. If you'd like, I can edit it for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I've edited my answer. Feel free to edit if something is missing.

Comment: Now available in mono (tested version 4.4.2)

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error on Ubuntu 16.04. I fixed it by upgrading my Mono installation. The [mono project's download page](http://www.mono-project.com/download/) has instructions for how to do that for different OSes.

To upgrade, I ran these commands:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/ubuntu xenial main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-official.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

`[FromBody]` works fine after that.